# Roblox my game .rbxl corrupted , what to do?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this error message showing when I try to open my file :

[image]

I can confirm that -9881054 isn't equal to 12923974.
Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you modified this rbxl at all? Or was this file just a locally saved place from Studio?

Comment: localy saved on my pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably find an automatically saved version of your place on your computer.

**Windows**: C:\Users[USER]\Documents\ROBLOX\AutoSaves

**MacOS**: ~/Documents/ROBLOX/AutoSaves

Comment: Yea it was corrupted too :/